# Install webrat with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rubygems 1.8.15

Tags: ruby, webrat

I want to use webrat in combination with Cucumber for writing acceptance tests for a web application. When I try to install the webrat gem I get the error stated below. I have tried to delete C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\cache* and a `gem update --system` without any luck.

I am trying to install the gem on Ruby in a Windows7 environment. As far as I can see the problem is related to this: "no metadata found in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/webrat-0.7.3.gem"

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

```
gem install webrat --debug
Exception `NameError' at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:177 - uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
Exception `Errno::EWOULDBLOCK' at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141 - A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. - read would block
Exception `Errno::EWOULDBLOCK' at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141 - A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. - read would block
Exception `NoMethodError' at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1483 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification name=webrat version=0.7.3>
Exception `NoMethodError' at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1483 - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Gem::Specification name=webrat version=0.7.3>
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247 - File exists - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
Exception `Gem::Package::FormatError' at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:122 - no metadata found in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/webrat-0.7.3.gem
Exception `Gem::InstallError' at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:121 - invalid gem format for C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/webrat-0.7.3.gem
ERROR:  Error installing webrat:
        invalid gem format for C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/webrat-0.7.3.gem
```

Comment: I had no issue with rubygems 1.8.17 on my Win7 machine. Have you tried `update_rubygems` or are you locked into 1.8.15?

Comment: Thank you for reply :) Webrat did the job, so I changed to it. Problem solved.

Comment: I will move it to an an answer then!

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though updating to [Rubygems 1.8.17](https://rubygems.org/pages/download) takes care of the issue. OP used `update_rubygems`.